# Google cloud speech to text C++

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-speech

I want to use google speech to text api in my c++ Qt/mingw application but I had a problems building c++ library for it. So I implement simple REST client for speech to text api it recognize small audio files. And now I want to use audio stream and there is no rest api for it. So I have a question, how can I implement client for streaming speech recognition without using all google libraries with dependensies. I have not find any examples for grpc api or even documentation about how does streeming speech recogniton work with grpc.

Comment: I found [multi-threaded](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe.cc) and [single-threaded](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe_singlethread.cc) examples right away. Not to mention the [googleapis definition of the protocol](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/cloud/speech/v1/cloud_speech.proto) linked from the README. (admittedly I had to click a bit to get there)

Comment: I saw this examples but it require a lot of dependencies, like grpc lib, protobuf, bazel build system to build api, maybe something else. I'm building my application for windows and all examples and installation guide which I found is for linux and it didn't work out of the box. I spent a day and did not manage to install all of it and build examples. So I write it with just a few http requests. It's just a few simple http requests with json for small audio files recognition. Can I write something like that for streaming recognition?

Comment: No. You need gRPC for streaming recognition.

Comment: But grpc is just json request sent via http isn't it? And I need just one packet to send audio data and one to receive text. Could it be done manually, sending and receiving http requests?

Comment: If you think implementing HTTP/2 and protocol buffers and managing all the streams is somehow easier than compiling gRPC, go ahead.